# flutter delete and update an item from listview and db

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I want to remove an entry from listview and db at the same time using swipe like this:

```
 onPressed: () {
      // Delete the item from DB 
      setState(() {
      data.indexOf(data[index]);
      data.removeAt(index);
      });
     Navigator.of(context).pop();
     },
```

the methode doesn't seem to be working also i want help with how can I trigger the update on this page without the user to reopen the page.

```
return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        List<Ia> data = snapshot.data;
                        print(data);
                        return Dismissible(
                          background: slideRightBackground(),
                          secondaryBackground: slideLeftBackground(),
                          key: Key(data[index].toString()),
                          // ignore: missing_return
                          confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
                            if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
                              final bool res = await showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return AlertDialog(
                                      content: Text(
                                          "Are you sure you want to delete                                   `                                              ${data[index]}?"),`
                                      actions: <Widget>[
                                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                                        FlatButton(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Cancel",
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                          ),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        FlatButton(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Delete",
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                                          ),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            // Delete the item from DB 
                                            setState(() {
                                              data.indexOf(data[index]);
                                              data.removeAt(index);
                                            });
                                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  });
                              return res;
                            } else {
                              // Navigate to edit page;
                            }
                          },
                          child: Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(data[index].name,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                              subtitle: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "Status",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    data[index].state,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 1):

Calling API in dismiss should be working,if you are using api to delete data from server database you need to call a delete function

**Sample UI Code**

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final items = List<String>.generate(20, (i) => 'Item ${i + 1}');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Dismissing Items';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final item = items[index];
            return Dismissible(
              key: Key(item),
              
              // what to do after an item has been swiped away.
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                // Remove the item from the data source.
                setState(() {
                 Deletedata(pass your id here);
                  items.removeAt(index);
                });

                // Then show a snackbar.
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$item deleted')));
              },
              // Show a red background as the item is swiped away.
              background: Container(color: Colors.red),
              child: ListTile(title: Text('$item')),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Delete function**

```
Future<void> Deletedata(String id) async{

var response = await http.delete(Uri.parse("http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/api/delete_route/$id"), headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Charset': 'utf-8', 'Authorization': 'token',},);
      print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');
}
```

Comment: Your method didn't solve my problem because it was related to the API but it guided me to the answer so i sincerely thank you for the time and the help you offered me

Comment: it's fine brother@amadeus4040

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're only removing it from the list, which is pointless as the stream is from the database. You need to remove it from the database only.
In your `onPressed()`, remove `setState()` and add this :

```
await _fireStoreInstance.runTransaction(
      (Transaction transaction) async {
        transaction.delete(YOUR_DOC_REF_HERE); // i'd assume data[index].reference
      },
```

Comment: it doesn't work can you please exlpain your method as for the database its an api

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: postgres im developping a flutter mobile app with odoo api

Comment: That info would be good to know. Check the DB documentation how to remove an entry.

Comment: this is an exmample in the documentation DELETE /api/product.template/?filter=[["id", "=", 95]] but i don't know how to use it with the swipe delete method